# Is an EEA registration certificate (EEA1) valid ID for travel within the Common Travel Area?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, common-travel-area, uk-residents, irish-citizens

I am an Irish citizen, resident in the UK & looking to fly back to Ireland without my passport (currently submitted for a driving licence application).

Wikipedia lists a number of documents as valid ID for travel to Ireland [within the Common Travel Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area#Travel_between_the_UK_and_Ireland), such as a work photo ID or bus pass, (though I unfortunately don't have these).

It also mentions *"National ID card/Government-issued photo ID cards"*. I do have an EEA1 residence cert — but I presume this wouldn't count as a National ID (which I think means the credit-card style ID carried in Spain, Germany, etc.)

Would it be considered a *Government-issued photo ID card* though? It's a blue, cardboard document rather than a plastic ID card:

[image: EEA1 Specimen image]

Comment: Didn't think the EEA certificate was applicable to Irish, who de facto have the right of abode in the UK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are challenged at a CTA port (which is unlikely), they will scan it and if nothing flags up, you can proceed.  You might get some stick about upgrading to the newer ID's, but that's reasonable.  Keep your DVLA reference number handy.

If you are an ROI citizen you are covered on UK side by the Ireland Act 1949 http://cain.ulst.ac.uk/hmso/irelandact1949org.pdf  On the ROI side there is a treaty agreeing to the Act.  These are more of an academic curiosity because the provisions are so widely known anyway.  The ROI Act is discussed here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Ireland_Act_1948

For re-entry into the UK, you also benefit from Paragraph 18 of the UK immigration rules, and they are SUPPOSED to assure that P18 still applies to you, but it's very doubtful that things would reach that point.

Comment: I'm flying back into Heathrow T1, where I've *never* seen an immigration check coming from Dublin. I'm more worried about flight/ground staff on the way over & then immigration control in Dublin itself. Good idea re bringing info on the DVLA application within me. Thanks Gayot!

Comment: @anotherdave, a pleasure, but no need for thanks:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers #